# Destroy/remove blaze template in meteor 1.0.4

Tags: meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I've discovered that both IronRouter aswell as FlowRouter do not re-render the template `itemListDetails` when passing from the first route to the second one. I know that this can be done and bypass by redefining the logic, but my target is to achieve the cleanest code as possible, also taking advantage of the latest `Template.subscribe` which can be called on the `OnCreated` function of the template.

```
FlowRouter.route('/:shop/items',{
 action: function(params) {
  FlowLayout.render('shopsLayout', {menu:'itemList'});
  FlowLayout.render('shopsLayout', {main:'itemListDetails'});
 }
});

FlowRouter.route('/:shop/items/:item',{
 action: function(params) {
  FlowLayout.render('shopsLayout', {menu:'itemList'});
  FlowLayout.render('shopsLayout', {main:'itemListDetails'});
 }
});

Template.itemListDetails.onCreated(function () {
 var shopN = FlowRouter.current().params.shopNumber;
 var self = this;
  self.autorun(function () { self.subscribe("itemsCollection", shopN); });
});
```

At the beginning I was thinking it is an IronRouter problem (as already listed somewhere also in stackoverflow), but when I switched to FlowRouter I've realized that this is not a bug: simply both routers do not re-create the template.. as it is already created.

My question is: How can I request to destroy/remove the `itemListDetails` template from an action on the other template?

Comment: using onRendered hook is not one solution ?

Comment: Tried already but it doesn't re-render. Probably the subscribe function cannot be used inside an onRendered hook

Comment: you should add iron router tag (you added meteor and blaze only)